# Lock table in form_validate and unlock on form_submit on Drupal 6

Tags: events, drupal, drupal-6, validation

I'm writing a form for a Drupal 6 module for people to subscribe to some activities, and would like to limit the available subscriptions.

I'm quite new to Drupal API, but was thinking in locking a table (with `db_lock_table` on validation, check if we still have a seat available, then, on form submit, insert everything on the database and unlock, to prevent race conditions.

Will this work? Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own event management system in drupal, why not leverage existing modules, taken from http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/adding-events-management-to-drupal-6/

Installing events and events subscription management to Drupal 6 is as easy as installing a few modules and doing a quick setup.

1. download and install the event module
2. download and install the signup module
3. enable the event module and all its sub-modules (don’t check datepicker if you want to go fast, as it will require additional CSS and JS to work)
4. enable the signup module (required by event-signup)
5. go to permissions and enable the events and signup features (nodes and signup sections) for user roles as needed (maybe you want to allow anonymous people to signup for events…)
6. go to content administration -> content type -> event -> edit
7. in the Signup configuration section, select any of the 2 last options (allowed or enabled) then save
8. create an event and “enable” the signup option (edit the corresponding elements to suit your needs)

The event signup module has the feature of "There are settings for restricting signups to selected roles and content types, and to place limits on the number of users that can signup for any given node." - see http://drupal.org/project/signup

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but these modules can't help me because I need some complex validations on the signup. The user must select several activities on the same event, but some of them can't be selected simultaneously according to the organisation's rules

Comment: I've never used these modules, but would it be possible to add your required validation to form(s) they provide?

Comment: don't know, but most probably I'd end up having to lock some tables, which leads me back to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

db_lock_table's point is to avoid race conditions. I don't see any other way of doing this.

Comment: my question is: "is the lock preserved between the validate and submit functions?"

Comment: The lock is preserved until you unlock it... or maybe I'm missing a point?

Comment: the functions I'm talking are actually hooks called by the drupal framework and not functions I am calling. If you're sure that the lock indeed is preserved across these hooks, I'll give the answer to you. Are you sure about it (or better, can you provide a reference for it?)

Comment: Well, I haven't tested, but the faster way for you to find out will be while testing out.